# Can it be proven that more than one vertex can individually be removed from a strong tournament and still be strong?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

One vertex can be removed from the vertex set, V(T), of a strong tournament, T, so long as |V(T)| is greater than or equal to 4. Any strong tournament has (at least) one Hamilton for every k, where k is a set of natural numbers greater than or equal to 3 and lesser than or equal to n, where n = |V(T)|. Therefore, a n- 1 strong graph exists because an n - 1 Hamilton cycle exists where one vertex can be excluded. But how can I prove that T can have more than one vertex that is not critical (T-x and T-y are both strong)?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com